# Entity Framework Database first with Web API

Tags: json, entity-framework, angularjs

Is is possible to use Entity Framework, web API together?

Application Structure:

1. Web API Application with AngularJS
2. Data Access Layer: with Entity Framework

In my Web API Application I want to use entities from DAL as a model.

Data return from Web API controllers should be JSON.

When I try it always gets error like this:

{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"$id":"2","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error while copying content to a stream.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"$id":"3","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.","ExceptionType":"System.ObjectDisposedException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateWrapper(Object list)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_c()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)"}}}

Here is my controller (Same code is working when I use Code First)

```
public class TodoController : ApiController
{
  // GET api/Todo
  public IEnumerable<Todo> GetTodoItems(string q = null, string sort = null, 
       bool desc = false, int? limit = null, int offset = 0)
 {
   using (var db = new AdvanceContext())
   {
     var list = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Todo>();

     IQueryable<Todo> items = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort)
              ? list.OrderBy(o => o.Priority)
              : list.OrderBy(String.Format("it.{0} {1}", sort, desc ? "DESC" : "ASC"));

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) && q != "undefined")
        items = items.Where(t => t.Description.Contains(q));

     if (offset > 0)
        items = items.Skip(offset);

     if (limit.HasValue)
        items = items.Take(limit.Value);

      return items;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It is possible to use both together. The problem is on your Web API. Can you add the controller you were trying to access?

Comment: Your DataContext is being disposed.
Change the using (var db = new AdvanceContext()) to:

var db = new AdvanceContext();

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in your context:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

**Example:**

```
public partial class Dbname : DbContext
{
    public Dbname()
        : base("name=Dbname")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<dtproperty> dtproperties { get; set; }
```